# Either the differential of the determinant of a basis vanish everywhere or nowhere along a path: what does this imply?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

This is from [Introduction to Relativity](https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToTheTheoryOfRelativityPart3/page/n7), By Begmann.

[image]

After equation 11.9a, Bergmann says:

> Along any path $\Delta$ satisfies a linear, homogeneous differential equation of the first order.  Therefore, it cannot vanish anywhere on that path if it does not vanish everywhere.

I don't understand why this is so. In particular in the case of a local Riemann normal coordinate system.  In such a coordinate system,  $\Gamma^i_{jk}=0$, and there is such a coordinate system available at every non-singular point of a Riemannian manifold.

Bergmann's assertion appears to imply that geodesically extending the coordinate curves of a Riemann normal system by a distance at which the effect of curvature cannot be neglected will maintain the vanishing of the affine connection coefficients.  In other words, a local Riemann normal system cannot smoothly mesh with coordinate system having $\Gamma^i_{jk}\ne 0$.

To clarify, if $\Gamma^i_{jk}= 0$ then eq. 11.9a gives no information about the non-singularity of$\Delta$. If the curve along which the $b$ basis is parallel transported passes through a neighborhood where the coordinate system is Riemann normal, the connection coefficients vanish.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. It breaks search functionality, and it doesn't work for blind users.

Comment: I live in my car, and cannot use a computer when the library is closed.  I am posting from an Android device without a keyboard.

Comment: Android devices do have keyboards.

Comment: The keyboard stopped working, and Walmart refused to honor their warranty on a Walmart branded tablet.

Comment: If you have a touch screen, then you have plenty of keyboard apps to choose from. If you don't have a touch screen, how are you typing the responses in?

Comment: Where in the image does it indicate the author is using Riemann normal coordinates? And what do you mean by normal coordinates? See "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates".

Comment: @KyleKanos:even typing an email reply on cell phone with the so-called Android keyboard sucks.

Comment: @Cinaed I used an Android keyboard for many years, doing nontrivial edits & comments on this site. It's doable, though nonoptimal.

Comment: @CinaedSimson He didn't say he was using them.  His development would be meaningless if he had used them.  But his conclusion appears to say that if the connection coefficients do not vanish at any point on the manifold, they will not vanish anywhere.  Perhaps he neglected to address the case I'm suggesting.

Comment: @CinaedSimson interestingly, this is part of Bergmann's production of Riemann normal coordinates, which is not the method described in the wiki page.  IIRC Schultz uses exponential mapping to establish them.

Comment: His argument is for equation $(19.a)$ - which use $\Gamma^{k}_{ks}$ - not the ones you posted. And $\Delta$ is the product of vectors. If one vector is missing, then vectors are no longer linearly independent, and $(19.a)$ is zero everywhere. Also note, $b_{i}$ implies the vectors are dual vectors - or co-vectors - the Christoffel symbols are slightly different. My guess is by "normal" you mean Cartesian but that doesn't mean the space if flat.

Comment: @Cinaed Simson $\Gamma^k_{ks}$ is simply the contraction of $\Gamma^i_{ks}$ using the Einstein summation convention. If the latter vanished so must the former.  $\Delta$ is the determinant of the basis being parallel transported.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos Please post a video showing us how to type equation 11.9 using the touch screen of an Android tablet holding it in one hand.  I would very much like to learn how to do that.

Comment: $\Delta \equiv \delta^{{i_1}...{i_n}}b_{1} \cdot\cdot\cdot b_{n}$ is a tensor where $\delta^{{i_1}...{i_n}}$ is the contravariant Levi-Civita tensor density. And the Christoffel symbol is not a tensor - they're summed over but there are no contractions. Further, since $\Delta$ is a tensor, the variation of the tensor - namely, $\delta\Delta$ is the operation which generates the $\Gamma$'s in equation $(11.9)$. See "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant". Comments aren't for extend discussions. And besides, three strikes and you're out.

Comment: Not sure why there's a restriction to holding it in one hand, as one can lay it on a lap, a table, dashboard, steering wheel, center console, etc in a car. Also not sure how I'd be able to take a video of myself doing something on my phone as my only recording device *is* my phone. But it is most certainly doable, just tedioous.

Comment: @CinaedSimson $\Delta \equiv \delta^{{i_1}...{i_n}}b_{1} \cdot\cdot\cdot b_{n}$ is a rank-0 tensor, AKA a scalar point function.  It is the determinant (Jacobian) of the differential matrix of the transformation from the coordinate system upon which the $\Gamma^i_{jk}$ are expressed, and the coordinate system spanned by the $\{b\}$.  That is, it is the contraction of the Levi-Civita tensor density with the components of the $b$ basis vectors.  *Contraction* means summing over indices.  It can be applied to tensors and non-tensors.  See Dirac's book on General Relativity, Chapter 7.

Comment: In general relativity, a vector is denoted as $v=v^{i}e_{i}$, which has repeating indices - as do all geometric objects. To claim a tensor is a scalar because it has repeating indices is nonsense.

Comment: @CinaedSimson These are some of my notes related to the subject of General Relativity https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NYMWfLyosWY5SCXxpr4NayowYoFBTpgT https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jhIy8h0vl9M-6ghTpGm7NEMqT949uTx6 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A3JIzmJugWS2_JPSfTsOVL6_K6uaq6Cy https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aDCpLJUsWZxw5cqPwaH-HgbeiBoE-90L https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fEG08GmPvJbsqu4p-cRDONn-wEb8updw https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l9dw1vnWtnR-2KN4oIweHR6QnTJhs0fs https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KoYOK1fTwCoNPmt32QEG4iIcpzSWjDdt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When Bergmann says "Along any path Δ satisfies a linear, homogeneous differential equation of the first order," he does not specify that the equation has constant coefficients.  I see nowhere that he states that the connection coefficients are non-vanishing in the neighborhood and on the coordinate system under discussion, but it is clear (to me) that this qualification is necessary in order for $\delta\Delta=\Delta\Gamma^k_{ks}\delta\xi^s\ne0.$ 
Furthermore, it is possible to parallel transport $\{\overset{i}{b}\}$ to a point where $\Delta\Gamma^k_{ks}=0$ while preserving their linear independence. So, I conclude that Bermann's statement is technically incorrect.

Comment: There's just one problem with the down-vote.  I am right.

Comment: Note, $\Delta\Gamma^k_{ks}$, are two different objects, $\Delta$ and  $\Gamma^k_{ks}$. See equation $(11.9a)$. It should be clear $\Delta$ doesn't vanish. Hence, you still need to prove $\Gamma^k_{ks}$ vanishes.

Comment: And why is the word "determinant" in the title? The author doesn't calculate a determinant in the page you posted  - the author doesn't even mention the word.

Comment: @CinaedSimson $\Delta$ is a determinant. It is a rank-0 tensor.  Summation on the contravariant indices of vector with the indices of the corresponding covariant basis vectors is not the contraction of two rank-1 tensors.  There are various interpretations of the result.  One interpretation is that it is the contraction of a rank-1 tensor with a rank-2 tensor (formed of the components of the basis). I added a clarifying paragraph to my question.